# Adding a UIPickerView to a UITableView cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uipickerview

I am trying to add a pickerView to a row in my table view, but after doing this, all I see is a black rectangle inside the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {       
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    pickerView = [[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200, 300)] autorelease];         
    [cell.contentView addSubview:pickerView];
    }
}
```

I really don't have a clue how to solve this.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Is the cell the correct size to hold the pickerView?

Comment: Do you not need to set some properties of the picker view so as it knows what to display? Try swapping out the UIPickerView with the UIDatePicker subclass so as you know it's definately got some content.

Answer (score 9):

May be this can help:  [DateCell with TableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Listings/MyTableViewController_m.html)

Comment: God bless you buffer_overflow... I was googling for hours until I found this answer. That example does exactly what I needed...

Comment: Facing an issue in apple DateCell example... Just replace all labels with text field and add few text fields. Text is not getting preserved after opening date picker. How to preserve text in text field when cellforrowatindex: method called after [tableview endupdate]